# How to convert the jQuery plugin to work in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Hello first of all i am sorry if the way i am asking my question is stupid i am learning JS and react at the same time.

My question is is it possible to use a jquery plugin to work in react i was looking alot of documentation online but couldnt make it work.

This is the script using type.js in my custom.js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    animate_text();

});

function animate_text(){

    var animateSpan = jQuery('.animation_text_word');

        animateSpan.typed({
            strings: ["Freelancer", "UI/UX Designer", "Web Developer"],
            loop: true,
            startDelay: 1e3,
            backDelay: 2e3
        });
}
```

And this is in my App.js file

```
<div className="text_typing">
<p>I'm a <span className="animation_text_word"></span></p>
</div>
```

i imported in into app.js or in index.js but seem to i cant make it work i know i guess i am way i out my game but would be nice to get some knowledge for this and yes i am trying to convert a static site into react just for fun and get to  know react and more.

this is the error i get when i do npm start

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6BWX.png

Thank you for any suggestion or help and i am sorry if my question wasnt in the right group or clear.

Comment: You can check the documentation to see if that helps: [Integrating with Other Libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)

Also, 
`
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    animate_text();

});
`

can be replaced by 

`
componentDidMount(){
    animate_text();
}`

They serve the same purpose, but the latter one is provided by React.

Here React expect to receive a function, but whatever you have here is not a function, you can try to convert it to a function to check if any error occurs.

Comment: JQuery is not needed any more. The DOM can be used directly, since support is good in modern browsers. Also, I would skip React at this stage of learning. It will just abstract away things that you would benefit from learning first.

Comment: thank you so much for the response. i was just curious with all the videos i was seeing i will just stick with the onces i am learning for now.

thank you